# Best practice: Where to resample PCM and which tool?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, kernel-module, resampling

I have developed a kernel module (Android) which provides me:

```
PCM
16-bit
48000 Hz
2 channel
```

and I want to stream it to an Apple's Airport Express (AEX) in java.

The AEX needs 44.1 kHz PCM so I have to resample the PCM-stream.

I have following possibilities, but which is the best?

### 1. Use the C-program "raop_play" (part of [raop-play](http://raop-play.sourceforge.net/))

```
advantages: 
            high-performant due to native C
            already uses libsamplerate to resample wav, mp3, ogg, flac, aac, pls
            openssl as static library
            usable via command-line from my java-program via Runtime.exec()

disadvantages:
            I am relative new to C
            overloaded: I don't need wav, mp3.. only PCM
            many dependencies with GPL-libraries which I have to compile for Android
            only supports PCM already with 44.1 kHz, no resampling for PCM implemented yet 
            -> have to implement resampling for PCM
```

### 2. Resample & stream in java (with [libresample JNI-bridge](https://github.com/intervigilium/libresample))

```
advantages: 
            I CAN java :)
            middle-performant due to resamling in C , but streaming in java
            just one dependency to LGPL-library
            no Runtime.exec() needed

disadvantages:
            needs [bouncycastle][3] for AES which is a bit larger than openssl
            less performant than solution #1 (but maybe fast enough)
```

### 3. Resample already in kernel module

```
advantages: 
            most performant
            no resampling at higher level

disadvantages:
            I am relative new to C
            Is it possible to use libsamplerate or libresample in kernel-space?!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a java-guy in heart, but this task (especially on a cpu constrained device, like a handheld) is crying for C. I would suggest simply using the libsamplerate. It has a simple API, and even if you're new to C you'll find plenty of examples by just googling around.

*of course the java based solution could and would work, it just doesn't seem polite to the users to eat up their batteries just because your new to C :)*

EDIT:
I might contradict myself a bit, but even though performance is a serious issue, I would avoid doing *anything* in kernel-space, unless I know the kernel and the hardware **really** well. In light of this I would go with a user-space program linked to libsamplerate. After a bit of googling around I've found this example (*note that the output is the jack interface, obviously it has to be different for you*)

```
#include <jack/jack.h>
#include <samplerate.h>

int channels;
float data_samplerate;


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void getDasData(float **dst,int num_frames){
/* Provide sound data here, and only here. */
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////



long getDasResampledData_callback(void *cb_data, float **data){
  static float ret[1024];
  static float ret3[1024];
  static float *ret2[2]={&ret[0],&ret[512]};
  getDasData(ret2,512);
  for(int i=0;i<512;i++){
    ret3[i*2]=ret2[0][i];
    ret3[i*2+1]=ret2[1][i];
  }
  *data=&ret3[0];
  return 512;
}

void getDasResampledData(float **dst,int num_frames){
  double ratio=samplerate/getSourceRate();
  float outsound[num_frames*2];
  long read=src_callback_read(dassrc_state,ratio,num_frames,outsound);
  //fprintf(stderr,"read: %d, num_frames: %d\n",read,num_frames);
  for(int i=0;i<read;i++){
      dst[0][i]=outsound[i*2];
      dst[1][i]=outsound[i*2+1];
  }
  if(read<num_frames){
    float *newdst[2]={dst[0]+read,dst[1]+read};
    getDasResampledData(newdst,num_frames-read);
  }
}


static int process (jack_nframes_t nframes, void *arg){
  int ch;
  sample_t *out[channels];

  for(ch=0;ch<channels;ch++){
    out[ch]=(sample_t*)jack_port_get_buffer(ports[ch],nframes);
  }

  if( (fabs(data_samplerate - jack_samplerate)) > 0.1)
    getDasResampledData(out,numSamples);
  else
    getDasData(outputChannelData,numSamples);
  return;

  audioCallback(NULL,0,out,channels,nframes);
}

int main(){
  dassrc_state=src_callback_new(getDasResampledData_callback,SRC_QUALITY,2,NULL,NULL);
  jack_set_process_callback(client, process,NULL);
}
```

> from http://old.nabble.com/Example-of-using-libresample-with-jack-td8795847.html

This example seems pretty straightforward, I hope you can use it.

Comment: I finally mixed solution #1 & #2: I've implemented the downsampling with "libresample" in a program in user-space. High-performant. I got headache with the 2 channels, but solved it :). Thank you!